# Is archery considered a martial art?

Tags: discussion

The title pretty much says it all. There are a lot of interesting techniques when it comes to archery, but are they considered on topic around here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exact question would be on topic for the [main site](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com). But if you are asking if archery *related* questions are on topic then that is difficult to answer without seeing the question. There are some aspects to (or practices of) archery that are rooted in the martial arts (i.e. [Kyūdō](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABd%C5%8D)), and there are also concepts originating from the martial arts that could be applied to modern sport archery.

In any case, the site is community driven. This means they can vote to close questions if it is believed to be off topic. This comes down to both the content of the question and how it is asked.

Sooo.... if your question is related to martial arts concepts or practices (even as applied to archery) then it is on topic. If it isn't on topic then we can always see if it will be on topic on the [Sports beta site](http://sports.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Good answer. I know this has been brought up in [another answer](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/62/what-questions-about-firearms-are-on-topic/67#67) as well. It touches upon the subject lightly, but as @slugster says, it depends on the exact question.